# How change ng-model by click?

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-click` event:

```
ng-click="changeSpecializationStatus(specializationMain[$index], $index)"
```

**Angular JS:**

```
$scope.changeSpecializationStatus = function (item, index){
    $scope.specializationMain[index] = (item == true) ? false : true;
}
```

I want to change value in element with $index on `true` or `false` after each click

Comment: Can I see your json of specializationMain?

Comment: you could do `ng-click="specializationMain[index]=!specializationMain[index]"`

Comment: Thanks, you can add this comment like as answer!

Comment: How I can do the same with function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do like this
I've passed array with index and boolean value, and display it in ng-repeat
HTML:

```
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type = "button" value = "{{s.index}}" ng-repeat = "s in specializationMain " ng-click = "changeSpecializationStatus(s.index)">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.specializationMain = [{"index" : 1, "value": "false"},{"index" : 2, "value": "true"}];


  $scope.changeSpecializationStatus = function (index){
    //alert(index);
    $scope.specializationMain[index - 1].value =!$scope.specializationMain[index - 1].value;
    alert($scope.specializationMain[index - 1].value);
  }
});
```

You can check in codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyydRo